# yes | long-interactive-script -- is it possible to avoid a busy infinite loop?

Tags: bash

My understanding of Bash pipes is that executing `a-process | another-process` would run `a-process` and `another-process` concurrently rather than wait for the former to finish before starting the latter. (Otherwise `yes | interactive-script` would make little sense). But if the interactive script takes a long long time to run, it would seem that `yes` would print so many yeses whereas the `interactive-script` probably needed only a few of them. This scenario makes me curious about a hodgepodge of questions:

- Am I correct to understand that `yes` will keep writing to the pipe the entire time until the script terminates?
- Suppose that I do some other work while `yes | long-interactive-script` runs. Will `yes` have non-negligible influence on (e.g., slow down) my other work?
- Suppose that the interactive script hangs. Will the stream of yeses accumulate somewhere so that it will eventually run out of memory and crash?
- Suppose that I want to answer yes only 12 times. Should I go with `(for i in $(seq 12); do echo 'yes'; done) | long-interactive-script`, or would there be a more elegant solution to this task?
- Suppose that I want to answer yes exactly as many times as the `interactive-script` requires. Is there a general way of determining whether `interactive-script` is blocked on input reading and providing yes only under such circumstances?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The thing that you are missing is that the pipe can only hold a limited amount of data.  Once the `yes` process fills that up (which will happen quite quickly -- a millisecond or less), it will be blocked and won't use any more CPU time until the second process reads some of the data.

On Linux, you can use `cat /proc/sys/fs/pipe-max-size` to see what the maximum limit for any pipe is (though the limit can be lowered on a per-pipe basis with `fcntl(fd, F_SETPIPE_SZ, size)`).

Comment: `/proc/sys/fs/pipe-max-size` controls the maximum (hard limit). `ulimit -a | grep pipe` shows the current restriction-- typically ~4KB.

Comment: Thanks -- didn't think about the pipe size. Would `yes`'s printing function block until enough room becomes available again in the pipe?

Answer (score 1):

The pipe will eventually fill, and `yes` will attempt to write and block waiting for stdout to become available. A negligible amount of memory (64KB on Linux according to [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/11946/how-big-is-the-pipe-buffer)) will be used to buffer the pipe.